# Trying to do a website checker, Doesn't seem to print to the excel result file

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a code for a website checker, it runs normally on my terminal but when it's printed to an excel file, it doesn't seem to print to the result excel file

I haven't found the solution to the answer

```
statuses = {
    200: "200, Website Available",
    301: "301, Permanent Redirect",
    302: "302, Temporary Redirect",
    403: "403, server understands the request but refuses to authorize it",
    404: "404, Not Found",
    500: "500, Internal Server Error",
    503: "503, Service Unavailable",
    509: "509, server has reached its bandwidth allowance",
    521: "521, Web server is down",
    522: "522, Connection timed out"
}
 
for url in website_url:
    
    web_response = requests.get(url)
    
    try:
        print(url, statuses[web_response.status_code])
        data = {
            'webphish' : urlgrab,
            'status' : statuses[web_response.status_code]
        }

        dfexcel = pd.DataFrame(data)

        with pd.ExcelWriter('Result.xlsx') as excel_writer:
            dfexcel.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name='Result', index=False)
 
    except:
        print(url, statuses[web_response.status_code])
```

Comment: Please try to produce [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This works absolutely fine!

Comment: I tried running it, but it now prints, but the result is wrong

Comment: You iterate in a loop, but overwrite the Excel file on each iteration. So you're likely only going to see the result for the last URL.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that the incorrect results are caused by inserting the `urlgrab` list in the `data` dict and overwriting the data. To get accurate results, add the data in a list within the dict and only write it to the Excel file at the end. This will ensure that the correct outcome is achieved.

```
website_url = urlgrab
 
statuses = {
    200: "200, Website Available",
    301: "301, Permanent Redirect",
    302: "302, Temporary Redirect",
    403: "403, server understands the request but refuses to authorize it",
    404: "404, Not Found",
    500: "500, Internal Server Error",
    503: "503, Service Unavailable",
    509: "509, server has reached its bandwidth allowance",
    521: "521, Web server is down",
    522: "522, Connection timed out"
}
 
data = {
    'webphish' : [],
    'status' : []
}
for url in website_url:
    web_response = requests.get(url)
    try:
        print(url, statuses[web_response.status_code])
        data['webphish'].append(url)
        data['status'].append(statuses[web_response.status_code])
 
    except:
        print(url, statuses[web_response.status_code])

dfexcel = pd.DataFrame(data)
with pd.ExcelWriter('Result.xlsx') as excel_writer:
    dfexcel.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name='Result', index=False)
```